# Обращение к БД в синхронном варианте

Tags: javascript, node.js

недавно начал изучать node.js и стал знакомится с mysql. Сейчас я использую асинхронный вариант функции query, т.е.

```js
handle.query("SELECT * FROM `table`",(err,res,row)=>{
  //do somethind
});
```

Но у меня появился вопрос, могу ли я тот же код исполнять синхронно, т.е. чтобы выполнение ожидало получения данных по запросу и только потом переходило к выполнению следующей строки?

Comment: Нельзя, поскольку в общем случае node.js однопоточный, в нем не следует запускать долгих и тяжелых синхронных операций.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko в случае со всякими билд-тулзами часто используют как раз всякие `fs.readFileSync`, но это вкусовщина, можно и на колбеках то же самое сделать

Comment: @StrangerintheQ Билд-тулзы не работают в многопользовательском окружении. Поскольку вопрос про выборку из БД, можно сделать вывод, что код будет запускаться на сервере. Соответственно, в контексте данного вопроса, синхронные операции использовать не следует.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko на 95% согласен с Вами, однако в той организации где я работаю, в процесс сборки встроен скрипт, который фетчит из нашей JIRA связанные тикеты и добавляет в `changelog`, правда это все написано на java, однако имеет место быть

Comment: @StrangerintheQ 95% - отличный показатель! Я сам с собой на столько бываю не согласен :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нельзя и не имеет смысла, node выполняет все в одном потоке и синхронность означает что весь поток будет ждать когда вернётся ответ